# ¿Mejor forma de modificar (update) un objeto con Spring y Hibernate en este escenario?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

No sé como avanzar con esto, a ver si alguien me da una mano :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el modal que se me en la imagen van a aparecer varias credenciales cargadas. Cada credencial se puede editar o borrar y estoy teniendo problemas de arquitectura para hacer el edit (soy nuevo con Spring y Hibernate).

Al clickear en editar hice que el modal de arriba sea reemplazado por uno nuevo con 3 inputs para hacer el edit:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

... desde acá no se bien como podría seguir y es donde necesito ayuda.

Lo que hice fue esto:

```
// Editar credencial de un FisicHost
$("#credentialsTable").on('click',"button[id^='edi-']",  (e) => {
    $('#credentialsModal').modal('hide');
    $('#editModal').modal('show');

    var credentialId = e.target.id;
    var newUser = $('#newUser').val();
    var newPass = $('#newPass').val();
    var newNotes = $('#newNotes').val();

    $.post( "/fisicHost/" + credentialId + "/credentials/update", data => {
    console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Se me ocurrió tomar el valor de los 3 inputs y luego hacer un post al controlador con esos 3 valores + el ID de credencial a editar ...

```
// Método para actualizar credenciales
@RequestMapping(value = "/fisicHost/{id}/credentials/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void updateCredential(@PathVariable(value = "id") String credId){
    String[] parts = credId.split("-");
    int id = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    Credential credential = credentialService.getCredentialById(id);
    credentialService.update(credential);
}
```

De acá me surgen preguntas como:

¿Como debo mandar esos 3 valores de los 3 inputs? Si se fijan en el post que hago, en la URL solamente estoy mandando el ID de la credencial que quiero actualizar, no sé como debo mandar esos 3 valores de inputs para validarlos en el controlador (y no los quiero mandar en la URL como con el ID de la credencial)!

Y segundo ... una vez recibido por el controlador y hechas las validaciones, como le devuelvo los datos actualizados del controlador a la vista ??

Toda ayuda, explicación será más que bienvenida.

Muchas gracias a todos

Answer (score 2):

Cuando haces un POST o un PUT, lo habitual es mandar los datos en el cuerpo de la llamada:

```
let credentialData = {
  dato1: ...,
  dato2: ...
};

$.post(url, credentialData).then(respuesta => {
  ...
};
```

Puesto que los datos se pasan en el cuerpo, deberás esperarlos en backend en el cuerpo:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/fisicHost/{id}/credentials/update")
public ResponseEntity<Credential> updateCredential(@RequestBody Credential credential) {
    ...
    return ResponseEntity.ok(respuesta); //respuesta es de tipo Credential
}
```

Esto significa que tendrían que crear una clase *bean* (simplemente con getters y setters) equivalente al objeto javascript que vas a mandar, para que Spring lo rellene automáticamente.

Esa clase se puede usar tanto para recibir los datos como para enviarlos en la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude hacerlo y es bastante parecido a esto !